# How to submit to a SharePoint 2013 list after jquery validate completes

Tags: jquery, validation, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to figure out another way to write the following Jquery function. Currently after my form validates successfully the form data does not successfully submit to the list. 
The line that is causing the issue is: (eval(" ( function () {" + js + " })();");

```html
$("input[value='Save']").each(function () {
               var js = $(this).attr("onclick");
              $(this).attr("onclick", "");//remove sharepoint click handler...
               $(this).click(function (event) {
                 if (!set_FieldValidation())
                   {
                       return false;
                   } else {
                     alert ("I'm going to save now");
                       //call sharepoint click handler..
                      
                      eval(" ( function () {" + js + " })();");
                      
                   }
               })
           })
```

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless the question is specifically about this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint PreSaveItem function is called when onClick event handler is fired for Save button in List Forms.
PreSaveAction function from another hand, allows to override behavior for a Save button. It is commonly used for client side validation, for example:

```js
 function PreSaveAction() {        

       if(set_FieldValidation())
       { 
         return true;
       } 
      else
      {
       return false;
      }
}
```

Delete your code added for Save button logic and add this code. Write your jquery validation function in set_FieldValidation(). 
Hope this helps:)

Comment: I made the updates as you suggested and I definitely think that is a better approach but unfortunately, the data is still not submitting to the SharePoint list. What I'm seeing is that after the validation and PreSaveAction completes the form fields clear which I would expect and the default SharePoint validate text appears, "You must specify a value for the required field" appear. Do you think the cause has anything to do with the fact that I updated all of the form fields to have a name attribute so that the Validation would work and now SharePoint does not  recognize them??????

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed. The SharePoint custom form has a Name attribute by default so when I change it using Jquery I'm basically breaking the page. The default NewForm.aspx does not have the attribute which I suspect makes all the difference in the world. I just wanted to close the loop.